# Video component not loading properly in production with nextjs,tailwindcss, typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

When this is pushed to production from Github to Vercel it has a rendering issue on mobile devices in firefox and chrome. When the video component renders in the homepage it doesn't fill up the whole viewport as desired. It initially renders in 16:9 video format filling out the width but leaving black space above and below the video. This only occurs for 0.2 second or so and then it returns the the proper format where the video is 9:16 vertical and the excess is clipped from view. I have refactored this a few times and I have the same problem every single time. This project is with next 13, tailwindcss, and typescript, with a sanity cdn. The CDN has no issue as the images and videos are showing on all pages locally and deployed.

```
"use client"

import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';  // Importing necessary dependencies from react
import { Homepage } from '../../types/Homepage';  // Importing Homepage type
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';  // Importing GetStaticProps from next
import { getHomepages } from '../../sanity/sanity.util';  // Importing function to fetch homepage data
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';  // Importing animation components from framer-motion
import Image from "next/image";  // Importing Image component from next
import Loading from '@/components/Loading'  // Importing Loading component

interface VideoHeroProps {
  currentIndex: number;  // Index of the current video
  homepages: Homepage[];  // Array of homepage data
  onVideoEnd: () => void;  // Handler for when the video ends
}

const VideoHero: FC<VideoHeroProps> = ({
  currentIndex,
  homepages,
  onVideoEnd,
}) => {
  const [exiting, setExiting] = useState(false);  // State to manage exiting animation
  const currentHomepage = homepages[currentIndex];  // Get the current homepage data
  const videoSource = currentHomepage?.video || '';  // Get the video source url
  const videoPoster = currentHomepage?.poster || '';  // Get the video poster url

  useEffect(() => {
    setExiting(false);  // Reset exiting state on index change
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => setExiting(true), 500);  // Set exiting state after a delay
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);  // Clear the timeout on unmount or index change
  }, [currentIndex]);

  if (!currentHomepage) {
    return <Loading image={'image/from/cnd'} />;  // Render Loading component if no current homepage data
  }

  const renderVideo = () => (  // Function to render the video element
    <motion.video
    initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
    exit={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.3}}  // Transition configuration
      className={` absolute top-0 left-0  w-screen h-screen object-cover ${exiting ? 'exiting' : ''}`}  // Classes for styling and animation
      key={videoSource}  // Key for React reconciliation
      autoPlay  // Autoplay attribute for video element
      muted  // Muted attribute for video element
      playsInline  // Playsinline attribute for video element
      onEnded={onVideoEnd}  // Handler for when the video ends
    >
      <source src={videoSource} type="video/mp4" /> 
      Your browser does not support the video tag. 
    </motion.video>
  );

  const renderImage = () => (  // Function to render the image element
    <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center">  
      <Image
        src={videoPoster}  // Source url for image
        loading='eager'  // Eager loading for image
        alt='Fallback image'  // Alt text for image
        priority 
        layout="fill"  // Layout configuration for image
        objectFit="cover"  // Object fit configuration for image
      />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className=" relative min-h-screen w-screen">  
      <AnimatePresence mode='sync'>
        {videoSource ? renderVideo() : renderImage()}  
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  try {
    const homepages = await getHomepages();  // Fetch homepage data
    return {
      props: {
        homepages,
      },
      revalidate: 60,  // Revalidation time in seconds
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);  // Log any errors
    return {
      notFound: true,  // Return not found if an error occurs
    };
  }
};

export default VideoHero;  // Export VideoHero component
```